# How to make list from get response

Tags: python, url, get

How to get list of URL-parameters from URL?
For example: `http://example.com/blank.html?access_token=blablabla&expires_in=0&user_id=ablabl&secret=rararar`.

I need to get `access_token`, `expires_in`, `user_id`, `secret`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`urlparse.parse_qs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) or [`urlparse.parse_qsl()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) to parse the query string:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs, parse_qsl, urlparse

query_string = urlparse(url).query
if query_string:
    data_as_dict = parse_qs(query_string)  # returns a dictionary with lists
    data_as_list = parse_qsl(query_string) # returns a list of tuples
```

Demo:

```
>>> from urlparse import parse_qs, parse_qsl
>>> url = 'http://example.com/blank.html?access_token=blablabla&expires_in=0&user_id=ablabl&secret=rararar'
>>> query_string = url.partition('?')[2]
>>> parse_qs(query_string)
{'access_token': ['blablabla'], 'user_id': ['ablabl'], 'secret': ['rararar'], 'expires_in': ['0']}
>>> parse_qsl(query_string)
[('access_token', 'blablabla'), ('expires_in', '0'), ('user_id', 'ablabl'), ('secret', 'rararar')]
```

Because any key in a query string can occur more than once, you can end up with more than one value per key. The `parse_qs()` function collects all values into lists per key, the `parse_qsl()` function simply returns each key-value pair as a tuple, letting you decide what to do with duplicates.

Comment: If you are using `urlparse`, isn't it better to use `urlparse.urlparse` or `urlparse.urlsplit` rather than `str.partition`?

Comment: @Robᵩ: It's a little overkill, in my experience. I find `str.partition()` just that little more.. handily available.

Comment: But your example deals poorly with `#`, as in `http://example.com/?q1=a1&q2=a2#label`.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Touché, that *is* a good reason to not use partition. Will update.